# Removing margin space CSS/HTML after animation fade out

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a database project for class and I wanted to make a GUI for it just for funsies. So, I am not too fluent in HTML/CSS and I need some help..

I want to make a fancy fade in/out message to ensure I have a working connection to my database. So I did some digging online and found a similar post:

[CSS how to make an element fade in and then fade out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125705/css-how-to-make-an-element-fade-in-and-then-fade-out)

It works perfectly in animation, however once it fades out all the margin space that once contained it is still allocated to the page; with that said, is there any simplistic way to removing all that unwanted space? I'll provided images to help illustrate what exactly I want it to look like...

[image: At page load]
[image: After animation ends]

Code used: (basically the same as the related post, see above)

```
<!-- dbGUI.php file -->
<!-- DATE -->
<!-- PHP -->
<?php
   $message = "";
   $con = mysqli_connect("#####","#####", "","store");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
          $message = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          } else {
          $message = "Connected to database...";
          }
        ?>      
<!-- END PHP -->
<!-- MARKUP -- >
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <!-- HEADER --> 
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Database Admin Portal</title>
   <!-- Favicon -->
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
   <!-- CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="dbGUI.css" />
   <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
</head>
<!-- MAIN -->
<body>
   <header>
      <div class="elementToFadeInAndOut"><?php echo $message; ?> </div>
      <nav>
      </nav>
   </header>
   <hr>
   <main>
      <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
      <section>
         <h2>HEADER 2</h2>
         <article>
            <h3>HEADER 3</h3>
            <p>
            </p>
         </article>
      </section>
   </main>
   <hr>
   <!-- FOOTER -->
   <footer>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>

    body
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:16pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

CSS File:

```
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end (100%) of your:

```
@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

you can add `display: none:` to remove the extra space that it was taking up.  You can take it one step further and add another transition before doing `display: none:`

Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Answer (score 1):

`display: none;` when you have completed the animation will hide it from the DOM and remove any space it was taking up.

`opacity` will make it transparent, but will still take up all the space it did when it was visible.

Some interesting links for you:

[CSS "Display: none;" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187939/css-display-none-property)

[Is there an opposite to display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630945/is-there-an-opposite-to-displaynone)